# Monaca app working in dashboard preview but not on Android 6 phone

Tags: javascript, android, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm trying to modify the basic todo-list example for Onsen-UI.

I've added a new button in the menu.

```
<ons-toolbar-button id="resptab" >
    <ons-icon icon="ion-pie-graph" size="28px"></ons-icon>
    Table
</ons-toolbar-button>
```

and a navigator wrapping the list

```
<ons-splitter id="splitter">
    <ons-splitter-side id="splitter-menu" page="menu.html" 
        side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
    </ons-splitter-side>
    <ons-splitter-content>
        <ons-navigator id="myNavigator" animation="slide" page="list.html"/>
    </ons-splitter-content>
</ons-splitter>
```

I'm pushing a new page from a script through an event listener

```
document.querySelector('#resptab').addEventListener('click', this.setRespTable.bind(this));
```

and a function

```
todo.setRespTable = function() {
    ons.notification.prompt('Switch to responsive table view',{
        title: 'Responsive Table',
        cancelable: true,

        callback: function(label) {
            document.querySelector('#myNavigator').pushPage('table.html')
        }.bind(this)
    });    
}
```

Everything works fine as expected in my desktop dashboard with the Preview but when I try it with Monaca Debugger on my Galaxy Android 6 phone, it fails with an error in the Log showing that `querySelector` is `null`

I’ve also noticed that the above said button is not shown in the menu when I run the app on the Android phone, while - again - I can see it from the dashboard Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Solved both issues by replacing the button with a menu item

```
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item data-filter="all" tappable>All</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-header>Status</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item data-filer="uncompleted">Pending</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item data-filter="completed">Completed</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-header>Responsive</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item id="resptab" ><ons-icon icon="ion-pie-graph" size="28px"></ons-icon>RxTable</ons-list-item>        
</ons-list>
```

and by setting the event handler in the menu init

```
document.addEventListener('init', function(event) {
    var view = event.target.id;
    if (view === 'menu' || view === 'list') {
        todo[view + 'Init'](event.target);
    };
}, false);
```

which calls

```
todo.menuInit = function(target) {
    document.querySelector('#resptab').addEventListener('click', this.setRespTable.bind(this));     
}
```

In the end of this [article](https://giuliohome.wordpress.com/2017/04/17/onsenui-for-mobile-cross-platform-front-end/) there is the corresponding version in OnsenUI with React, an extract from the render function below:

```
<Page>
    <List dataSource={['Searching', 'Lists', 'Twitting', 'Google Drive','Settings']}
    renderRow={(title) => (
        <ListItem key={title} 
        onClick={() => this.hide2title(title)} tappable>{title}
        </ListItem>
    )}/>
</Page>
```

In the latter case, notice the array function to pass value to method.